# Problem usage 12 cpu core

Tags: macbook-pro, cpu

I was checking the workload of my CPU cores during a use case of computation. I noticed that only one half (odd only) is used as you see in image.

Why are the others not inactive?

Notice that this computation has took more than 15 minutes.

With radeon Pro 560X and CPU
[image: OS info]

[image: Workload CPUs]

Comment: Is the computation application doing single threaded workloads?

Comment: I do not understand the question but there’s no multiple threading in the code.

Comment: If there is no mulitiple threading it means the app is single threaded which means it runs on only one core at a time

Comment: So this is ok there’s no problem on my cpu?

Comment: However the cores having 0 is odd - we need to know exactly the mac model, CPU type and OS version

Comment: @user151019 Let me add thes informations on the post

Comment: It okay, I see can see task on others core now, https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ob0jB.png but why they did not start at same time?